# Lubuntu installed on 50 laptops

Tags: system-installation

I am refurbishing laptops for 2 schools in Nepal and I will be setting up at least 50 laptops with Lubuntu 14.04 with educational software.

What is the most efficient way of replicating the same OS with applications on many different laptops?

Comment: Visit [Edubuntu](http://www.edubuntu.org/) which is education oriented.

Answer (score 4):

You can use clonezilla. It's the most efficient way of installing the same OS on many systems. I use it all the time. Please, refer to this [tutorial](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image) here for further information.

But mind these instructions below, otherwise you might get errors while saving or restoring lubuntu through clonezilla.

1. Do a fresh install of Lubuntu in one of your computers.
2. Always see that the hard-disk size where your clonezilla will restore the image is larger than or equal to the hard-disk size from where your image was made.
3. SEE to it that the sda numbers of backup and restore drives are SAME, i.e, if you are making the backup from sda1 then restore it to sda1. There is a work around for this but it may lead to many errors.

Hope it helped.

If you need further instructions then please comment below. Thank You!

Comment: It is very useful because I keep on experimenting with my Ubuntu system and if somehow I run into some errors and my system crashes I can restore back to a previous point.

Comment: If you set them all up for webmin, you can manage them all collectively, using Webmin's Cluster ability. Would definitely do the install the same, e.g.- custom image or clonezilla.
http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/ClusterWebminServers

Answer (score 3):

If the laptops have different hardware and/or you don't want to clone the hard drive, you can use [Ubuntu Customization Kit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/uck/) to build a custom ISO with all applications, languages and updates pre-installed.